# Intermitant error Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server[53]

Tags: php, sql-server-2005, iis-7

I've searched through the Internet with respect to this error and I've not found anyone who is having this problem on an intermittent basis. It seems my application will run for an extended period of time with no problem, then all of a sudden it stops working and I get this error. Then after some time(I have no idea how long this is) the application will start working again. But lately to correct the problem I just restart the IIS server. Could there be a problem with the application pool? There are no errors in any of my event logs.

My server configurations are as follows Windows 2008 64-bit running PHP 5.4. I'm connecting to a SQL Server 2005 on Windows 2003.

Here is my error.
Thanks for any help

Connection could not be established.
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 53 [code] => 53 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => HYT00 [SQLSTATE] => HYT00 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 53 [code] => 53 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. ) )

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this problem many times and found that this happens because of improper DNS configuration at server level. Hence, namedpipe fails. The solution i discovered is to create odbc (@ client) using tcp/ip address instead of domain name of sqlserver.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your Server's IP address lease expires, get's renewed but the DNS record does not get refreshed?  It sounds like your server does allow remote connections but for whatever reason, it looks like it is not being found.

Comment: All my servers use static IP addresses. But last night it got me to thinking that on my new Web server, I did not input any wins server IP addresses. Also for the second DNS server, I am putting an external one. So I changed my Web server to use an internal wins server and only my internal DNS servers. I will see if this corrects my problem. So far my application has been up and running for 12 hours without crashing.

Rick

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved my problem. I changed my new Web server to only use my internal DNS. I also entered values into my WINS settings for the web server. The error has not occurred since. I hope this helps anybody else who is having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Named database (default catalog) does not exist on the specified server (host). I get this error on attempt to connect to a linux environment that has no SqlServer at all.